# Python String Manipulation (SUM values)

Tags: python, string, sum

Whats the fastest & easiest way to SUM all the numerical values before the "M's" and "I's" in this next string: **"1S20M1I9M2D120M"** so here we have **20M, 1I, 9M en 120M.** which would be 150. Whats the easiest way to count this in Python? Because I have like +- 50000 of such strings (with all different kind of values ranging from 1 - 150), and I can't figure out an easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex for this:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "1S20M1I9M2D120M"
>>> sum(int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+(?=[MI])', s))
150
>>> sum(int(m.group()) for m in re.finditer(r'\d+(?=[MI])', s))
150
```

Comment: Thanks! Workt perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Also using regex( `re.split()` )

```
import re

s = "1S20M1I9M2D120M"
p = r'[MI]|\d+[SD]'

result = sum(int(i) for i in re.split(p, s) if i)
# re.split(p,s) => ['', '20', '1', '9', '', '120', '']
>>> print result
150
```